# Perform a query with an entity field condition with multiple values

Tags: 8, entities, database

I have a content type that has a entity reference field that allows users to add multiple taxonomy terms in that field. I'm attempting to perform queries that grab nodes that have a specific set of taxonomy terms within that field.

Using one value in that field works fine, like so.

```
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
        ->condition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
        ->condition('type', 'custom_type')
        ->condition('custom_taxonomy', 2)
        ->sort('field_last_name', DESC);
```

Where 2 is the id of the term I'm searching for. However when I attempt to search for nodes that contain two specific terms like so,

```
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
        ->condition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
        ->condition('type', 'custom_type')
        ->condition('custom_taxonomy', [2,8])
        ->sort('field_last_name', DESC);
```

I receive the error

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match
>   number of tokens:

I've also attempted

```
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
        ->condition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
        ->condition('type', 'custom_type')
        ->condition('custom_taxonomy', [2,8], 'IN')
        ->sort('field_last_name', DESC);
```

Which doesn't fail, but doesn't provide the intended results. It displays every node that has either term 2 **OR** term 8. Instead of term 2 **AND** term 8 as intended.
How would I perform a query that checks if a node has multiple specific values in an entity reference field?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use two separate `andConditionGroup()`:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
  ->condition('type', 'custom_type');
$and = $query->andConditionGroup();
$and->condition('custom_taxonomy', 2);
$query->condition($and);
$and = $query->andConditionGroup();
$and->condition('custom_taxonomy', 8);
$query->condition($and);
$result = $query->execute();
```

This works no matter how many terms are in the field or in which delta they are.

**Edit**

This results in this SQL:

```
SELECT base_table.vid AS vid, base_table.nid AS nid
FROM 
{node} base_table
INNER JOIN {node_field_data} node_field_data ON node_field_data.nid = base_table.nid
INNER JOIN {node__custom_taxonomy} node__custom_taxonomy ON node__custom_taxonomy.entity_id = base_table.nid
INNER JOIN {node__custom_taxonomy} node__custom_taxonomy_2 ON node__custom_taxonomy_2.entity_id = base_table.nid
WHERE  (node_field_data.status = '1') AND (node_field_data.type = 'custom_type') AND( (node__custom_taxonomy.custom_taxonomy_target_id = '2') )AND( (node__custom_taxonomy_2.custom_taxonomy_target_id = '8') )
```

Comment: He tried an equivalent code above and it returned no values, did you check that this code works?

Comment: Yes, it works for the standard article and tags field filled with multiple tags.

Comment: Maybe my suggestion failed because I wrote it like so `$and->condition('custom_taxonomy', [2], 'IN')`, `$and->condition('custom_taxonomy', [8], 'IN')`

Comment: That doesn't matter, just tested it, works with `'IN'` too. What makes the difference is the two separate AND groups.

Comment: Nice, didn't know this works. Makes sense, as this forces multiple joins internally.

Answer (score 9):

To do complex queries as you asked, you will need to use a condition group and to query the delta.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
  ->condition('type', 'custom_type')
  ->condition('custom_taxonomy', [2, 8], 'IN')
  ->condition('custom_taxonomy.%delta', 2, '=')
  ->sort('field_last_name', DESC);
$or = $query->orConditionGroup();
$or->condition('custom_taxonomy.0.target_id', 2);
$or->condition('custom_taxonomy.0.target_id', 8);
$query->condition($or);
```

See [QueryInterface::condition](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3Acondition/8.3.x) documentation.

Comment: I implemented the answer, but for some reason it's not displaying the proper results. If I use only one of the $and conditions, like [2], 'IN' or [8], 'IN' it displays the results just fine, but when I use both, I don't get any results. I triple checked to make sure I have nodes that have both.

Comment: Thinking about it, there is no need for the AND conditionGroup because the entityQuery uses AND by default.

Comment: Okay I changed it to just using $query->condition() but I'm still having the issue that when using both it doesn't display any results.

Comment: As per the [QueryInterface::condition](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3Acondition/8.3.x) documentation you can apply conditions on the delta.
I'll update the answer with an example code.

Comment: @Eyal, the AND condition group seems to be redundant, but it really helps to specify multiple conditions for the same field. You only need to put each condition in a separate AND group.

Comment: Attempting this caused an error 'Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryException: Invalid specifier 'value' in Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Tables->addField() (line 282 of /var/www/aaep.org/http/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Tables.php).'

Comment: Because the property name is `target_id` and not `value` (who gave you that idea ;-) )

Comment: hmm, I'm still not getting any results from that query

Answer (score 1):

```
$taxonomy_term = 'taxonomy_term';
    $vid = 'name_taxon';
    $terms = $this->entity_type_manager->getStorage($taxonomy_term)
      ->loadTree($vid);

foreach ($terms as $term) {
  $term_data[] = [
    "vid" => $term->vid,
    "name" => $term->name,
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 9 looks like this

```
$userStorage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('user');

$userQuery = $userStorage->getQuery();
$result_user_ids = $userQuery->accessCheck(FALSE)
  ->condition('field_user_nodes.target_id', [1,2,4], 'IN')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->execute();
// Above ^^ 
return $userStorage->loadMultiple($result_user_ids);
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I tested it with D9.3 and the result is the same as described by the post owner. @4k4 's solution still works though.