# How can I add multiple conditions for the same field taxonomy term in views query?

Tags: views, 8, database

I make some query for views filter for nodes. Use in [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/8.2.x).

```
$definition = [
   'table' => 'node__field_characs',
   'field' => 'field_characs_target_id',
   'left_table' => 'taxonomy_index',
   'left_field' => 'tid',
   'operator' => '='
];
$join = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.views.join')->createInstance('standard', $definition);
$rel = $query->addRelationship('node__field_characs', $join, 'taxonomy_index');
$query->addTable('node__field_characs', $rel, $join, 'node__field_characs');
```

I add array of conditions.

```
$q_and = db_and();
foreach($ch_id as $key => $val_array){
   $q_and->condition('node__field_characs.field_characs_target_id', $val_array, 'IN');
}
$query->addWhere(0, $q_and);
```

But if array $ch_id have more then 1 elements, it works wrong. It does not show any nodes.

A similar problem is described here [Perform a query with an entity field condition with multiple values](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226396/perform-a-query-with-an-entity-field-condition-with-multiple-values). But how can this be applied in this case?

Answer (score 0):

you try this code:

```
$and = $query->andConditionGroup();
foreach($ch_id as $key => $val_array){
   $and->condition('node__field_characs.field_characs_target_id', $val_array, 'IN');
}

$query->condition($and);
```