# Query to fetch users with specific roles

Tags: entities, 9

I'm using the following code.

```php
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('user');        
$query->condition('uid', [302,330], 'IN') 
  ->condition('status', 1, '=')
  ->condition('field_membership_status.value', 'paid', '!=')  
  ->condition('roles', ['individual','organization'], 'IN')
  ->condition('roles', ['organization_member'], 'NOT IN'); 

$uids = $query->execute();
  
$users = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->loadMultiple(array_values($uids));

foreach ($users as $user) {
  $type= "Final membership reminder";
  \Drupal::logger('my_module')->notice("email to ".$user->getAccountName());
  \Drupal::service('vc_mailer.email.service')->send_email($type, $user);
}
```

One of the user accounts has the following roles: authenticated, individual, and organization_member. This user account is still returned by the code; it  seems like the code ignores the last condition. What is the problem?

`condition('uid', [302,330], 'IN')` is just to constrain the query to those members for testing purposes.

The SQL query is the following.

```sql
SELECT "base_table"."uid" AS "uid", "base_table"."uid" AS "base_table_uid" FROM "users" "base_table" INNER JOIN "users_field_data" "users_field_data" ON "users_field_data"."uid" = "base_table"."uid" INNER JOIN "user__field_membership_status" "user__field_membership_status" ON "user__field_membership_status"."entity_id" = "base_table"."uid" INNER JOIN "user__roles" "user__roles" ON "user__roles"."entity_id" = "base_table"."uid" WHERE ("users_field_data"."uid" IN ('302', '330')) AND ("users_field_data"."status" = '1') AND ("user__field_membership_status"."field_membership_status_value" != 'paid') AND ("user__roles"."roles_target_id" IN ('individual', 'organization')) AND ("user__roles"."roles_target_id" NOT IN ('organization_member'))
```

Comment: You probably need to put the conditions in `andConditionGroup()`. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226396/perform-a-query-with-an-entity-field-condition-with-multiple-values

Comment: I shouldn't need to, they are all 'AND' condtions

Comment: Have you cast the query object to a string to see what the actual SQL would be?

Comment: Have you ensured the machine name you're using is the same as the system?

Comment: yes, $user->getRoles() returns "authenticated, individual, organization_member "

Comment: andConditionGroup() doesn;'t work either. I gave up and just used if(!in_array('organization_member', $user->getRoles())) { when processing the results

Answer (score 0):

**Snippet code to get users with some role but not some other role**: Drupal 9/10:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('user');
$Group1 = $query->orConditionGroup()
->condition('roles.0.target_id', 'organization_member', 'NOT IN')
->condition('roles.0.target_id', NULL, 'IS NULL');
  
$Group2 = $query->orConditionGroup()
->condition('roles.1.target_id', 'organization_member', 'NOT IN')
->condition('roles.1.target_id', NULL, 'IS NULL');

$Group3 = $query->orConditionGroup()
->condition('roles.2.target_id', 'organization_member', 'NOT IN')
->condition('roles.2.target_id', NULL, 'IS NULL');

$Group = $query->andConditionGroup()
  ->condition($Group1)
  ->condition($Group2)
  ->condition($Group3);

$query->condition('uid', 0, '<>');
$query->condition('roles', ['individual','organization'], 'IN');

$query->condition($Group);
$result  = $query->execute();
```

**Additional Info:** let's say **site has 3 roles**, excluding authenticated & anonymous role
if you want to get user who has not role 'organization_member' then
you have to check that role 'organization_member' for each role's row
for individual user **as role is multiple value field.**

**Analysis:**
**#1:** I also found some of articles where used query like this:

**$query->condition('roles.target_id', 'organization_member', 'NOT IN');**

Which interpret like this when query execute:

```
'roles.target_id' = 'roles.0.target_id'
```

So It 'll not scan through all the roles rows for each user entity, then
unexpected result will be returned, it seems that 'NOT IN' operator not work with role field of user.
**But in actual role is multivalue field.** require to use 'NOT IN' operator for per role row.

**#2:** With uid 'NOT IN' conditon works fine , as uid is single value field similarly goes with the type field of node.